# Sorting posts ordered by custom field value

Tags: custom-field, sort

I have a series of posts (using a wp-zoom theme). I would like to create a custom field called `order` and sort by that field.

Here is part of my homepage code:

```
<?php 
$z = count($wpzoom_exclude_cats_home);
if ($z > 0) { 
    $x = 0; 
    $que = ""; 
    while ($x < $z) {
        $que .= "-".$wpzoom_exclude_cats_home[$x]; 
        $x++;
        if ($x < $z) {
            $que .= ",";
        } 
    } 
}      
query_posts( $query_string . "&cat=$que" );
if (have_posts()) : 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "orderby" parameter of [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).
You must specify your custom field and you must give it a numeric value.
Short example:

```
query_posts($query_string . "&cat=$que&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=your_custom_field")
```